# Heroku Rails 4 assets não carregam

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deploy, heroku, rails4

#### Depois que fiz o deploy esses arquivos abaixo não estão sendo carregados.

[image: erro console chrome]

#### Este é meu diretório

[image: diretórios]

#### Este é meu application.rb

[image: application.rb]

Aqui como eles estão sendo chamados

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "home" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "home" %>

<img class="client" src="<%= asset_path('b.png') %>">
```

#### update:

Percebi não são só esses assets listados, nenhum asset está carregando.

Answer (score 0):

### Resolvido

Os erros estavam dentro dos arquivos `scss.erb`. Eles não chamavam corretamente os helpers do rails `image_tag` e `asset_path`.

Meus arquivos scss.erb estava como abaixo.

**Errado**

```
background: url(<%= image_path 'fake_slider.png' %>) no-repeat 0 0;
```

**Jeito certo**
Coloquei eles dentro de aspas duplas `" "` e depois tudo funcionou

```
background: url("<%= image_path 'fake_slider.png' %>") no-repeat 0 0;
```